# Dynamic jQuery method Chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am sure the answer is simple, but I am trying to figure out how to pass a chain of jQuery methods into a function as an arguement. The idea is that the methods executed on a DOM object could be dynamic. I am trying to write some qUnit tests where centralizing this kind of functionality would be useful. Example:

```js
function changeElement(el, methods){
  $(el).methods;
}

var elMethods1 = $(this).is('visible');
var elMethods2 = $(this).css('background', 'blue').append('appended text');

var el1 = $('.container1');
var el2 = $('.container2');

var result1 = changeElement(el1, elMethods1); // expect to return true/false
console.log(result1);

var result 2 - changeElement(el2, elMethods2); // expect to return DOM object
console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container1'></div>
<div class='container2'></div>
```

Comment: You could use bind on a function to get a function object with this set the way you want it. e.g.  methods.bind(el) so that whatever methods is, 'this' is now el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write each string of methods as a short function, like so:

```
var elMethods1 = function(jq) { return jq.is('visible'); }
var elMethods2 = function(jq) { return jq.css('background', 'blue').append('appended text'); }

var el1 = $('.container1');
var el2 = $('.container2');

var result1 = elMethods1(el1); // expect to return true/false
console.log(result1);

var result2 = elMethods2(el2); // expect to return DOM object
console.log(result2);
```